# What is the algorithm behind the saturate and brightness css filters?

Tags: css, css-filters

If I apply `filter: saturate(50%)` to `#FF0000` (that is HSB: 0, 100, 100) I expect to obtain `#FF8080` (that is HSB: 0, 50, 100)

BUT (you can try)

instead I obtain `#9B1B1B`...

What are the algorithms behind the saturate and brightness filters?

Comment: You already have saturation value on `100` `saturate()` will increment the saturation value but can't go more than 100 so I guess recalculate the new values what you are expecting to happen is **unsaturate** and as far I know you can't use negative values

Comment: I guess that the difference comes from the gamma function

Comment: @DaniP I don't think so, the w3schools site says "0% (0) will make the image completely un-saturated. 100% is default and represents the original image"

Comment: @vals can you explain better?

Answer (score 2):

The CSS filter saturation function is based on the SVG Filter spec for feColorMatrix/saturate but performed in the sRGB color space. The applied matrix is as follows:

> ```
> | R' |     |0.213+0.787s  0.715-0.715s  0.072-0.072s 0  0 |    | R | 
> | G' |     |0.213-0.213s  0.715+0.285s  0.072-0.072s 0  0 |    | G | 
> | B' |  =  |0.213-0.213s  0.715-0.715s  0.072+0.928s 0  0 | *  | B | 
> | A' |     |           0            0             0  1  0 |    | A | 
> | 1  |     |           0            0             0  0  1 |    | 1 |
> ```

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement